# 400 Bad Request in Movable Type import

Tags: import, movabletype

I have a Movable Type installation running the latest version of MT (currently Movable Type version 5.2.7 with: Community Pack 1.72, Professional Pack 1.53) and my client has provided us with a data export from another MT installation (we're migrating servers) that he would like imported to the new MT installation.

Unfortunately, every time we try to execute the import we receive

"Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

This is the ONLY part of the MT install which has this problem. I'm about to rip out the import tool and write my own processing script to do the job, since I'm not going to manually add ~750+ blog posts by hand.

Appreciate any advice that people can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide some more information? This doesn’t directly address your error, but might help you move on.

I am curious if you are doing an “Import Entries” from within a particular blog, or if you are at the system or website level and doing a “Restore”. The former uses simple text files with not much more information beyond title, body, author, category, while the later uses a nearly complete export of an MT installation that is usually contained in a ZIP file.

If you are able to do a “Backup” of the applicable blog(s) with the source installation, you might be able to “Restore” that to the destination installation by copying the ZIP archive to the %MT_DIR%/import directory. Note the MT version numbers should be identical for a “Backup”/“Restore” operation, which might require upgrading the source installation first.

Comment: You sir, win the internet :) I was doing a plain-text file import, NOT the backup/restore, but your comment about the %MT_DIR%/import folder caught my eye. I have been attempting to UPLOAD the text file via the file uploader tool on the import form - I never knew why the field was labeled "optional", but I didn't know about a built-in Import directory. After FTP'ing the text file to the server's /import directory, I brought up the File Upload form and simply clicked "Import Entries". Viola, all my data is in the system. Thanks!!

Comment: Great to hear! You’re very welcome!